# I have created 3 tables which contain Parent, Child, Mark and I want to combine three tables together using union query

Tags: sql-server-2008

In `Parent` table:

```
Id int (primary key),
Firstname varchar(50),
Email varchar(50)
```

In `Child` table:

```
Mid int (primary key),
Mark1 int,
Mark2 int,
Id(foreign key)
```

In `Mark` table:

```
Uid (primary key),
Mark3 int,
Id int (foreign key)
```

I want results to be like using Union query:

```
Id Firstname Mark1 Mark2 Mark3
-- --------- ----- ----- -----
1   john      80    70    60
```

Comment: It's a typical join query but not a union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join your tables not union them.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Firstname, c.Mark1, c.Mark2, m.Mark3
FROM Parent p
INNER JOIN Child c ON p.ID = c.ID
INNER JOIN Mark m ON p.ID = m.ID
```